# MacTex 2015 Installation fails

Tags: macos, installation, tex-live

I am using a Mac air with OS Mavericks. I currently have the 2014 version of TexLive installed via MacTex.  I opened it to update my Latex, and it required updates. Ok, after updating TexLive I relaunch and it gives me a message that TexLive2014 is no longer supported and I should install the 2015 version, with a link to the MacTex2015 download page. Upon downloading and launching the installation kit, I walk through the series of "continue" buttons with no real options (I say no real options b/c it give me false options, namely "install for all users?" for which I can't change the "all users" option, and "change the directory"). This is not consequential, and I prefer the defaults, just weird those were asked, but not a real option. Finally, when you click install it just gives an error message (w/ a picture of their mascot cartoon dog and Indiana Jones guy in the background) that says "Installation failed". No other information is given.

All users have admin privileges, so that is not the issue.

Logging in with another user I can download and install MacTex 2015 (recall I have to choose install for all users). Now back to my user, when I open TexLive 2014, I get the message "TexLive is pointing to the 2014 repo." and it tells me I need to point to the 2015 repo. Some reconnaissance shows that in `usr/local/texlive` i have a "2014" folder, but not a "2015" folder.

Any idea how to make this installation work?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I uninstalled TexLive (both deleted the folder and moved the icon in Applications to the trash) as recommended [here](https://tug.org/mactex/uninstalling.html). Then I ran `brew install Caskroom/cask/mactex` . It installed fine! Upon opening, TexLive I had to get my TexLive updates, then my Latex updates. Perhaps the original version was installed by brew and it caused problems when the 2015 version tried to install? In any case, fixed. :)